# How do i justify every line of text to same width - and fit to div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I'm trying to make this fiddle work correctly when resizing the browser. But it flickers with only every second rendering correctly rendered. I can't figure out why, but i would like it to adapt to a div instead of using the font size of the first line.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FlemmingH/qsn12ugx/)

```
.divtext {
  display: table;
  font-family: impact;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

<div id="container">
  <div class="divtext">THIS IS JUST AN</div>
  <div class="divtext">EXAMPLE</div>
  <div class="divtext">TO SHOW YOU WHAT</div>
  <div class="divtext">I WANT</div>
</div>

function changeSize(){
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("divtext"),
    refWidth = els[0].clientWidth,
    refFontSize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(els[0],null).getPropertyValue("font-size")),
    i = 1;
    while(!!els[i]){
      els[i].style.fontSize = refFontSize * refWidth / els[i].clientWidth + "px";
      i++;
    }
}

$(window).resize(function(){
        changeSize();

});
```

[image]
... and resizable.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the window.resize event by adding Throttling.

https://jsfiddle.net/s8xL7d1p/

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      // only run if we're not throttled
    if (!throttled) {
      // actual callback action
      changeSize();
      // we're throttled!
      throttled = true;
      // set a timeout to un-throttle
      setTimeout(function() {
        throttled = false;
      }, delay);
    }  
  });  
});
```

please refer http://bencentra.com/code/2015/02/27/optimizing-window-resize.html

Comment: No flicker, but the whole point was to accomplish a left and right alignment of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you're asking, but removing `display: table` gets rid of the flicker.

Comment: Doesn't help. I want the right and left alignment of the lines. Try to resize the browser in and out a couple of time and you'll see the error's.

Answer (score 0):

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("divtext")
var refWidth = els[0].clientWidth
var refFontSize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(els[0], null).getPropertyValue("font-size"))
function changeSize() {
  i = 0
  while (!!els[i]) {  
    els[i].style.fontSize = refFontSize * refWidth / els[i].clientWidth + "px";
    i++;
  }
}
window.resize = changeSize
```

Comment: This resize function is only called once, so i'm not able to resize the container accordingly.